# Ledger Copies (Hyperledger Fabric)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have installed hyper-ledger fabric, run the sample first network and perform the transaction using the chain-code but I have some following questions:

1-Where I can see the Performed transaction block.

2-How can I see the ledger copies on a different peer?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Hyperledger Explorer]

I am using [hyperledger/blockchain-explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) to see block data.

Comment: Thanks lissdy it is very helpful to analyze the whole channel components